# Magento 2 invoice email not sending

Tags: magento2, database, email, sales-order, smtp

My customer complaint they do not receive the email order. So I have to manually send them the invoice from the admin account.

What cloud is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked but I don't see any answers that reflect my experience. For me, the issue has been narrowed down to a few situations. First off, check your mail logs to see if the email was actually sent. Sometimes you get good feedback and an exact reason why the email didn't send.

- For me I use mailgun and I got an error recently saying that a user complained about emails (marked as spam probably). It was only one user, and they later complained about not getting emails! It was simple to correct the issue.
- Emails sometimes go to spam or with Gmail they can go to the "Promotions" inbox, confusing users. Have your user check their spam or junk. It's amazing how often this is the case.
- Email can be blacklisted for various reasons, check your email server's IP address on [mxtoolbox.com](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx) under blacklist and take corrective actions. If you are flagged, a shared IP address can cause this, or you may have malware on your server.

So really it comes down to two areas. The origin; it isn't sending from your server or hits a fatal error in Magento. Or the destination, a third party blacklist, or the final server is filtering out or hiding the email.

If it's not sending at all, check your Magento and PHP error logs. If it's not sending invoices only, but password reset, etc., work, then it's almost certainly Magento.